# RPM failed dependencies: libgdbm.so.2()(64bit) on Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, rpm, dependencies

i try to install RHEL5 x64 rpm package( mochapro-4.1.2-9658.x86_64 )  on Fedora 22, but it wants libgdbm.so.2()(64bit) library which is absent in dnf. 
it gives following error:

```
Error: nothing provides libgdbm.so.2()(64bit) needed by mochapro-4.1.2-9658.x86_64
```

i tried using rpm search and it seems gdbm-1.8.0-38.el6.x86_64.rpm has the library, but when i try to install it, it won't. if i try to install it with --allowerasing, it wants to remove dnf altogether.
i also tried unpacking rpm by converting rpm2cpio and passing it to cpio, which got me the library file, which i copied to /usr/lib64/ but the rpm package does not seem to see it.
if i install with --nodeps, rpm installs does not launch.

is there a way i can manually resolve the dependency with liblibgdbm.so.2 i've extracted?

---

ended up creating dummy .rpm file, which helped bypass dependency issue, but i get segmentation fault 5337 error when i launch, i guess its due to fedora22/rhel5 differences

Comment: Wat gave you the idea that RHEL packages are compatible with Fedora? Sure, RHEL branches off (sort of) Fedora, but normally some 2 or 3 releases back... your Frankenstein monster will just call all pitchfork and torch bearing citizen...

Comment: sry i'm new to linux, as you probably can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work. RHEL5 and RHEL6 have different libraries. You can spend days rebuilding the old libraries to fit your new Fedora 22... However it is **much** easier to start up virt-manager, create new virtual machine with CentOS 5 and install there mochapro-4.1.2-9658.x86_64.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. i didn't consider virtualization due to overhead, as stuff i do is intensive on ram/cpu/io

Comment: Today virtualization consume less then 1% of resources as overhead.

Comment: i've thought more like 14-20%. do you have a link to a relative benchmark?